# PHP preg_match_all issue

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

So I have written a little script that will log into my email and search each message for certain links. When the email is/has HTML bodies, everything works fantastic all is hunky dory... However, when the email is TEXT, there is some sort of difference that is preventing the match from being found.

This is my method of escaping my link pattern to check for in emails. My variable placeholder is *.

```
 $found = false;
 $escape = array('\\','/','(', ')', '?', '&');
 for ($i = 0; $i < $link_count; $i++) {
     foreach ($escape as $e){
        $links[$i] = str_replace($e, "\\$e", $links[$i]);
        $links[$i] = str_replace('*', '.*', $links[$i]);
      }
 }

 while (true) {
 $index = strpos($body, 'http://');

if ($index === false){
        break;
    }

$body = substr($body, $index);
$part = explode('"', $body, 2);
$part = explode(' ', $part[0], 2);
$part = explode("\n", $part[0], 2);
$part = explode("'", $part[0], 2);
$part = explode("<", $part[0], 2);
$tag = trim($part[0]);

foreach ($links as $link) {
    preg_match_all("/$link/", $tag, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        $found = true;
    }
}
```

From HTML Email This this is found to be a match:
http://knowndomain.com/something.php\?id=......*\&md=......*\&mu=......*-->http://matchingdomain.com/couldbe.php?id=1&md=2&mu=tr

BUT in a text email, the same check fails

My question is what the heck am I missing here. All outputs just before the check are the same!?

Comment: Are your text emails using [quoted-printable encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) ?. You might need to detect if it's a multipart message first and decode as needed.

Comment: The text emails are not using quoted-printable encoding

Comment: Are the links in `$tag` when you run the regex?

Comment: Yes, they are within the $tag variable.

Comment: Can you please add the value of `$link` and `$tag` when the issue is present?

Comment: $link = http:\/\/knowndomain.com\/something.php\?id=......*\&md=......*\&mu=......*
    $tag = http://knowndomain/something.php?id=1&md=2&mu=tr

Answer (score 0):

So I found maybe the issue maybe not.. It really did not have anything todo with the HTML or Text email as I thought.. it was actually the fact of a slight difference on each link.

So I remove $links[$i] = str_replace('*', '.*', $links[$i]); from my excape loop and put it just before the preg_match.

Tested and works so I wont question this for now.